# Import project (jar) into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import, package

I got a .jar file which I need to import into Eclipse. However, I don't want to have the jar as a referenced library. I need the .jar to be included like a "normal" project, with packages(!) and .java files.

I tried to do the following:
New Java project -> Import -> General -> Archive File. In this case, when I place this jar also as a referenced library, it is imported but with .class files.

New Java Project -> Import -> General -> File System. Imports the .java files, but the packages are lost and are normal folders. Also, the files are somehow strange, because the "j" in the icon looks differently, and errors are not noticed (no underlining)

Importing "Existing Projects into Workspace" doesn't work at all, it says that there is no project. I also tried to import the jar as a zip after extracting it, this gives me the -java files, but it destroys the packages.

Does anyone know how to import this correctly?

Comment: Import the jar then attach the source?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have managed it this way:
New Java Project -> Java settings -> Source -> Link source (Source folder). There I added my decompiled jar and it was imported correctly :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also create a new Java Project and then do File -> Import -> General -> Archive File.  This will save you a step of unzipping your jar and adding as a linked source folder.

Comment: This works if you select the src folder as a target and not the project folder.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot import a jar that way, unless it has the source code packed in the jar. If you really need the source code, you'll have to find an archive somewhere. But of course, not everyone is willing to share his source...

Comment: I managed it (see answer below)  - however I cannot accept my own answer right now. I know that not everyone is willing to share his code, but this is a company project.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the below and it worked.

1. Create a New Java Project
2. Goto `File` > `Import` > `General` > `Archive File`
3. Select the required Archive file(`.jar` in this case) from your local system.
4. Select the project you created in Step 1 and click `Ok`

This will save you a step of unzipping your jar but if there are `.class` files, eclipse won't convert them to `.java` files. This has to be done seperately.

Comment: This works if you select the src folder as a target and not the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Below helps in all recent eclipse.

Please try below eclipse plugin to import jar as project :

Step 1) Eclipse Help > Eclipse Marketplace 
Step 2) Install the plugin "Import Jar As Project" 
Step 3) Restart Eclipse 
Step 4) File->Import->Other->Jar without source 
Step 5) Select a jar/war file and click finish

New project will be created from the jar

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/import-jar-project

Thank You.